# Toggling class on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, event-handling

I am using this code to add a class on mouse hover to a link button and remove it on mouse leave.

```
jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-1 > .banner-wrap__inner > .banner-wrap__desc > .banner-btn > .btn-link").hover(function () {
    jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-1 > .banner-wrap__inner").toggleClass("active");
    jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-1").toggleClass("active");
});

jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-2 > .banner-wrap__inner > .banner-wrap__desc > .banner-btn > .btn-link").hover(function () {
    jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-2").toggleClass("active");
});

jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-3 > .banner-wrap__inner > .banner-wrap__desc > .banner-btn > .btn-link").hover(function () {
    jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-3").toggleClass("active");
});

jQuery(".btn-align > .btn-inverse").hover(function () {
    jQuery(".service-box__style-1").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need some [CSS hover rules](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)?

Comment: We could give you better advice if you also included your HTML so that we can understand what you are really trying to accomplish. (The generated HTML will do; we probably don't need to see the WordPress code that produces the HTML.)

Answer (score 1):

Is hard to evaluate jquery without the DOM when you are making selectors.

You are using a lot of `>` check if you can use [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

In a initial, state, theres a few lines repeated. that can be extracted in a outside function.

```
function toggleClass($container) {
    $container.find(".banner-wrap__desc > .banner-btn > .btn-link").hover(function () {
            $container.toggleClass("active");   
    })
 }

toggleClass(jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-1"));
toggleClass(jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-2"));
toggleClass(jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-3"));
```

And the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/ja5py40o/

Comment: I have try this code and its working! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could store in a variable so that the Dom doesn't need to be traversed several times:

```
var myvar = jQuery(".banner-wrap__color-1 > .banner-wrap__inner > .banner-wrap__desc > .banner-btn > .btn-link");
```

Then just use myvar instead of retrieving it again...
A

Comment: He doesn't query the same object more than once. The top level object is numbered 1,2, and 3

Comment: couldn't he get the parent node, then get the children when needed?

Comment: I think the hover function should be assigned to .btn-link then let the parents be grabbed as needed.
...but .banner-wrap__color-1 is an oddball and has more being done.
And I kinda want to see the html behind this, for a better assessment.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yrralej/qgLxa16r/1/ please refer to this link for my complete code. ThankYou!